# Question about chapter "the conditional distribution of the arrival time" in the Poisson Process.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

I am studying stochastic process written by Sheldon M Ross.

I have a question about the conditional distribution of the arrival time.

---

### Theorem 2.3.1

$$S_1, S_2, \cdots, S_n |_{N(t)=n} \sim U_1, U_2, \cdots, U_n$$
where
\begin{align}
S_i&\mbox{: i-th arrival time, } ~i=1, 2, \cdots, n \\
U_i&\mbox{: ordered Uniform distribution in time } t\in (0, t), ~i=1, 2, \cdots, n \\
\end{align}

The textbook proved using the fact that joint probability of $S_1, S_2, \cdots, S_n |_{N(t)=n}$ is same as that of $U_1, U_2, \cdots, U_n$ like:

\begin{align}
f_{U_1, U_2, \cdots, U_n}(u_1, u_2, \cdots, u_n)=\frac{n!}{t^n}\\
f_{S_1, S_2, \cdots, S_n|N(t)=n}(s_1, s_2, \cdots, s_n|n)=\frac{n!}{t^n}\\
\end{align}

---

I understand the above. However, I am wondering whether
$$S_i |_{N(t)=n} \sim U_i$$
is correct or not.

Thank you for reading my question, and I am sorry about whenever I am asking.... without answering.

Comment: The $U_i$ follows a ordered uniform distribution on $(0, t)$, or equivalently a beta distribution scaled by $t$.

Comment: Oh thank you. I edited

Comment: More generally, if two random vectors have the identical joint distribution, then each pair of corresponding random variables have the identical univariate marginal distribution. You are performing the same integration on the same joint pdf over the same support, so you obtain the same marginal pdf.